# How to create unique relationship using NeoEloquent

Tags: laravel-4, neo4j, eloquent, neoeloquent

I have just started using Laravel. I have not used Laravel Eloquent before. So I am directly using it on graph database using NeoEloquent. 
I know I can create relationship using hasMany() and attach() methods. But I want to create relationship only once. Has anybody used NeoEloquent for creating Unique Relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `hasOne()`relationship instead of `hasMany()` which will ensure that only one relationship of the specified type exists for the model.